# Override Parent component styles in child component

Tags: css, angular

I have a Parent component `parent.html` and it has `CSS` styles like below

```
.style1{
color:red
}
.style2{
color:red
}
```

and I'm reusing this component in `child.html`. Now I want to override the parent component styles in child component.
I try to use `::ng-deep` it is working but if  load `Parent component`, what are the styles overrides in child component it is reflecting in parent component also..

I want to override  only styles in child component but should not reflect in parent component. How we can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you need to use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in parent and then you will be able to add the override by adding more specific selector like in child component -

```
child-component .style1{
   color:red
}

child-component .style2{
   color:red
}
```

Comment: Can you give some live examples in this?

Comment: I'm using this parent component in `router-outlet`if I use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` then it is not taking other styles. here I want override only selected styles not all the styles

Comment: You can leverage  `ngStyle` and `Input` to override the specific property.  Demo link is updated as well. Please check same link.

Comment: It is not accepting if I write style class, if I write inline style it is accepting

Answer (score 0):

I think you must be having two components with 2 seperate directory and it should have html, ts, css files.

So in parent component's html you will reference child component - 
**parent.component.html** `->` `<app-child> </app-child>`

In the child component you should have - child.component.html, child.component.ts, child.component.css files.
If you create and add any similar styles like parent.component.css file in child.component.css then those will get added to each component like `p[random_atttr_value]`, so now you will have seperate styles for p in child.

This is default behaviour of angular, comes in view encapsulation. Used by angular like shadow DOM techonlogy which is not supported by all broswers but angular does it like this.
In other words it adds some attributes to each component rendered on browser.
ViewEncapsulation has 3 options -

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, 
           ViewEncapsulation.Emulated, (-- this is default)
           ViewEncapsulation.Native (-- only applies to browsers with shadow DOM technology)<br>
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.